# Can someone teach or explain to me this CVE?

Tags: vulnerability, cve

The CVE number is 2012-2089.

I don't really understand what this summary of cve meant.

Buffer overflow in ngx_http_mp4_module.c in the ngx_http_mp4_module module in nginx 1.0.7 through 1.0.14 and 1.1.3 through 1.1.18, when the mp4 directive is used, allows remote attackers to cause a denial of service (memory overwrite) or possibly execute arbitrary code via a crafted MP4 file.

Can anyone explain to me or possible give me a guideline on this vulnerability??

Answer (score 2):

In the versions of nginx listed, when handling mp4 files, an attacker could send a malicious mp4 file. Because of a potential buffer overflow situation, the contents of the mp4 file will be written to a part of memory that nginx doesn't expect to be changed. This could cause nginx to crash (denial of service) or, if the attacker can structure the mp4 file correctly, nginx could execute the contents of the file.

Comment: what is nginx???

Comment: Have you tried searching for the word on google?

Comment: nginx is an open-source web server. google nginx and read their website and wiki page